# How to improve my input commands

Tags: python, if-statement, input, while-loop

I am looking for any suggestions that will improve, simplify or even tidy up my input commands. I have seen that repetition is not a good habit.

```
while(char.health > 0):
    print("_____________________________________")
    line = input("\n>").lower().split()
    if len(line) < 1:
        print ("{} doesn't understand the command?".format(char.name))
    elif line[0] == "go":
        commands.movement()
    elif line[0] == "quit":
        commands.quit()
    elif line[0] == "rest":
        commands.rest()
    else:
        print ("{} doesn't understand the command?".format(char.name))
```

I have seen some people use a dict like this :

```
    cmd = {'go' : commands.movement()}
```

When I do this it seems to run the def without them being called!

---

Solved.
I have figured the solution out.

```
cmd = { "go" : (commands.movement)}
```

This is my new commands dict. I realized that `commands.movement()` is calling the def.

```
while (char.health > 0):
    print("_________________________________________")
    line = input(">").lower().split()
    if len(line) < 1:
        print ("Invalid command!")
    elif line[0] in cmd:
        cmd[line[0]]()     #this now calls the def instead
    else:
        print("Invalid command!")
```

Comment: Either post a proper answer or delete the question. I'd go with the latter since I'm pretty sure this is a dupe, but good job on figuring it out on your own. And no, there's nothing wrong with posting an answer to your own question.